# Is there any JCL REST Client available?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

How to call a REST API from JCL mainframe code. 
Is there any client library available for this?
Please Share.

Comment: No, what are you trying to do ????

Comment: I am trying to use Atlassian Jira's REST API in my mainframe batch jobs.

Comment: and my mainframe code is written in JCL or SAS

Comment: JCL is not a programming/scripting language. It simply tells the mainframe that you want to execute one, or more, programs and the resources needed by those programs. You need to look at the programs being executed to see which ones need to be amended - if any.

Comment: not possible from standard JCL batch job. I do not know what SAS offers, but CICS provides HTTP access.

Answer (score 2):

The z/OS operating system has several ways in which a program can issue a REST request to an API or service running elsewhere.  The most complete solution is provided by [z/OS Connect Enterprise Edition](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/connect-enterprise-edition). This product delivers a simple and intuitive way to consume data and services using the standard API/REST technologies of HTTP/HTTPS and JSON.

For environments where z/OS Connect EE is not an option, batch programs (which is what I assume you mean by "from JCL") can take advantage of the [z/OS Client Web Enablement Toolkit](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.ieac100/ieac1-client-web-enablement.htm) which provides an HTTP protocol enabler and a JSON parser. If your REST service is using XML instead of JSON, z/OS also provides an XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot submit REST requests from JCL directly. However, you can write a REXX exec, which can be executed as a job step, to submit REST requests using the z/OS Client Web Enablement Toolkit callable services.

Answer (score 1):

SAS has support for making REST calls from programs running in batch (JCL).  Its the SAS program that does the REST call, the JCL simply starts the SAS program.

This [short paper](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings16/SAS6363-2016.pdf) should get you started